# CRM 2011: Email attribute "from", how to predefine it?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

Where can I find the rulles, describing which field should be predefined (and it's value) by creating of a new record in dynamics? I already use the mapping table and it is usefull for some entities and fields, but there are no rules for such fields like "from" in email.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking: "How do I set a default value for a lookup field?".

The short answer is you can't.

The longer answer is you can, if you are willing to use something like JavaScript to customise the form.